# Div no centro ao lado da outra

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um site, criei algumas divs e queria que elas ficassem uma ao lado da outra centralizadas, já tentei com float mas ela fica em baixo.

CSS:

```
.fundopython{
    background:#232323;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    padding:5px;
    background-image:url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}

.fundocurso{
    background:#232323;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    padding:5px;
    background-image:url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}

.frente{
    opacity:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    color:#fff;
    transition: all .2s;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    font-family:verdana;

}

.frente:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bu - Cursos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li id="settings">
                <a href="https://github.com/bu"><img src="icons/github.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="options borda-direita">
                <a href="#">Cursos</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="search">
                <form action="" method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
                    <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="options">
                <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="outros.html">Outros</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
            <li>
                <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
        <script src="prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <br>
        <p class="line anim-typewriter">Certificados</p>
        <br>
        <div class="fundopython">
            <div class="frente">
                <h2>Python</h2>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="fundocurso">
                <div class="frente">
                    <h2>Python</h2>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara basicamente suas `divs` estão fechadas de forma errada, ficou uma dentro da outra, por isso o `float` não funcionava. A `div fundocurso` tinha ficado dentro da `div fundopython` ai não era possível uma ficar ao lado da outra já que uma estava dentro da outra...

E apesar de eu não indicar `float`, segue ai seu código corrigidos usando `float` e com as `div` fechadas corretamente. E para centralizar eu indico colocar as duas `divs` dentro de um *container* e nesse *container* vc usa `margin: auto` e `width: max-content`.

```css
    .fundopython {
    background: #232323;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
}

.fundocurso {
    background: #232323;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
}

.frente {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #C0C0C0;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    font-family: verdana;

}

.frente:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="https://github.com/bu"><img src="icons/github.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="options borda-direita">
        <a href="#">Cursos</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
            <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" />
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
            <li><a href="programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
            <li><a href="pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="outros.html">Outros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<br>
<p class="line anim-typewriter">Certificados</p>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fundopython">
        <div class="frente">
            <h2>Python</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="fundocurso">
        <div class="frente">
            <h2>Python</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O float Funciona como um ponto flutuante referente a algo, utilize o float no seu bloco principal, assim irá fazer com que suas duas divs flutuem referente a ele, e tambem utilize o float nas duas divs para que ambas peguem a flutuação.... Utilize tambem o clearfix() para remover possiveis bugs no site referente a flutuação....

Segue como criar o clear fix

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Além da falta do fechamento das divs, não é recomendado usar `<br>`
>   para dar espaçamento entre os elementos. A tag `<br>` deve ser usada
>   somente para quebra de linha entre elementos do tipo [phrasing
>   content](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Categorias_de_conteudo). Em vez disso, use `margin`.

Em relação ao alinhamento das divs, você pode incluir as duas divs em uma div pai flexbox. Além de uma ficar ao lado da outra automaticamente, você pode também centralizá-las com a propriedade `justify-content: center;`.

Veja:

```css
.fundopython{
background:#232323;
width:200px;
height:250px;
padding:5px;
background-image:url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
}

.fundocurso{
background:#232323;
width:200px;
height:250px;
padding:5px;
background-image:url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
}

.frente{
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#C0C0C0;
  color:#fff;
  transition: all .2s;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  font-family:verdana;

}

.frente:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.flexbox{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
   <div class="fundopython">
      <div class="frente">
         <h2>Python</h2>
         <br>
         <br>
         <p>
            Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="fundocurso">
      <div class="frente">
         <h2>Python</h2>
         <br>
         <br>
         <p>
            Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já estava utilizando o `flexbox`, mais de forma incorreta, pois você estava aplicando nos itens e não em um container (`div`) por trás deles.

Segue um exemplo utilizando o `flexbox`:

```css
.certificados {
 display: flex;
 justify-content:center;
}

.fundopython{
 background: #232323;
 width: 200px;
 height: 250px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-image: url(https://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/python2-720x405.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 5px;
}

.frente{
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #C0C0C0;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all .2s;
 
 transform: scale(0.9);
 font-family:verdana;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li id="settings">
      <a href="https://github.com/bu"><img src="icons/github.png" /></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
   </li>
   <li class="options borda-direita">
      <a href="#">Cursos</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
         <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
         <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   </li>
   <li id="search">
      <form action="" method="get">
         <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
         <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
      </form>
   </li>
   <li class="options">
      <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
         <li><a href="hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
         <li><a href="programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
         <li><a href="pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
         <li><a href="outros.html">Outros</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
   <li>
      <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<br>
<p class="line anim-typewriter">Certificados</p>
<br>
<div class="certificados">
  <div class="fundopython">
   <div class="frente">
   <h2>Python</h2>
   <br>
   <br>
   <p>
   Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
   </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fundopython">
   <div class="frente">
   <h2>Python</h2>
   <br>
   <br>
   <p>
   Curso Completo<br>da Linguagem<br>Python 3.7 
   </p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```